# Why is shear force half the total force?

Tags: forces, structural-beam

When applying a perpendicular force to a beam which is fixed on either side then the shear force is given by $V=\frac12 F$.

My intuition says that this is because the force $F$ is distributed over two fracture surfaces on either end of the beam.
Is there a more formal reasoning for this fact?

Does the formula hold for beams of any type of cross-section and for different loading conditions and boundary conditions?

Comment: Are you talking about F applied to the center of the beam and where the mass of the beam is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you eluded this is not a property of the beam, but the fact that there are **two** support points resisting the force $F$.

But if the point of application of the force isn't in the middle, then the shear force through the beam *will not* be $\tfrac{1}{2}F$

[image: fig]

Imagine a force $F$ supported by $A_y$ and $B_y$ as seen above. The proportion of the force taken up by each support depends on the geometry of the problem and the location of the force.

Now consider the sections of the beam near each support and you will realize that the shear force through each section *must equal* the support force, $ S_A = A_y$ and $S_B = B_y$ in order to maintain static balance.

So, in general, the shear force *is not one half of the applied force* but rather some other proportion depending on the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition says that this is because the force $F$ is distributed
> over two fracture surfaces on either end of the beam. Is there a more
> formal reasoning for this fact?

You haven't specified details of the loading conditions for the beam, but it appears you are referring to a simply supported beam with a vertical load applied to its center and where the mass of the beam is ignored. Under this symmetric loading condition the reaction at each support is $F/2$. Then, cutting the beam at any section along its length to either side of the applied load the magnitude of the vertical shear force at the section must be $F/2$ for vertical equilibrium of the section.

> Does the formula hold for beams of any type of cross-section and for
> different loading conditions and boundary conditions?

It only holds for the loading condition specified above. The vertical shear force does not depend on the type of cross section. But the vertical shear stress does depend on the type of cross section.

For loading conditions other than specified above, you need to first determine the reaction forces and, if applicable, reaction moments, depending on the type of support(s) involved using the equations for equilibrium, i.e., $\sum F=0$ and $\sum M=0$. Then, to determine the shear force at any section, you cut the beam to isolate the section then apply the equations for equilibrium for that section to determine both the shear force required for equilibrium.

> I didn't factor in the weight at all. The question is whether I would
> need to.

Yes, unless the magnitude of the weight is insignificant compared to the downward force $F$. The following assumes the weight is NOT insignificant compared to $F$. As such, the weight will change the reactions at the supports and change the vertical shear forces in the beam.

FIG 1 below shows the beam. It assumes the applied vertical force $F$ is applied vertically downward at the center of the beam. If there were no other forces downward forces involved, then the magnitude of the vertical shear is $F/2$ all along the beam except at the point of application of $F$ where the shear is not defined as it passes through zero and changes direction.

The weight of the uniform beam is represented by a distributed load $w$ where $w$ is the weight per unit length of the beam, or $w=mg/L$ and $m$ is the mass of the beam.

Before you can determine the applicable formula for the vertical shear in the beam, you need to determine the reactions at the supports. See FIG 2. For the purpose of determining the reactions, one can assume the weight of the beam acts as a concentrated load at the center of the beam. The resulting reactions required for equilibrium are then as shown in FIG 2.

Next, to determine the equation(s) for the shear force at any given section of the beam, one puts back the distributed load and draws a free body diagram of a section of the beam that has been cut. See FIG 3. In this case we are looking for an equation for the shear force as a function of the distance $x$ from the support at A, where $0<x<L/2$, that is, for any cross section between the support at A to the left of application of the force $F$.

The resulting equation for the vertical shear of the left side of the beam as a function of $x$ becomes

$$V=\frac{F+mg}{2}-\frac {mgx}{L}$$

At the point of application of $F$ the vertical shear is undefined, crossing the zero point and becoming negative. For the right side of the beam the shear equation is

$$V=\frac{-(F-mg)}{2}-\frac {mgx}{L}$$

FIG 4 shows the shear diagram for the vertical shear all along the length of the beam.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The beam has a uniform mass distribution and uniform cross-section. Does that mean that the mass can be ignored, or is there some other prerequisite condition?

Comment: Is force F separate from the weight of the beam?

Comment: Yes. I didn't factor in the weight at all. The question is whether I would need to.

Comment: Of course you would need to include the weight

Comment: Why would I need to factor in weight? The force isn't even applied in the same direction as gravity and my beam is fully supported from underneath. I think you are assuming some parameters of my problem.

Comment: @Angelorf I don't understand what you are saying. Isn't the force F being applied vertically downward on the beam? That's the direction shown in the answer you accepted, which does not account for the weight of the beam.  And isn't the force of gravity acting on the beam also acting vertically downward as well?  And  aren't the reactions at the two supports acting upward so that the sum of the vertical forces acting on the beam is zero for equilibrium?

Comment: You really need to provide a drawing so we know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Angelorf Bottom line: Unless the weight of the beam is insignificant compared to the force $F$, it must be included to determine the vertical shear equation. For what it's worth, I have updated my answer to show how.

Comment: The figure in the accepted answer is a top view for my purposes. However, that was never mentioned, because gravity is not relevant to my application. That's why the orientation of the beam was never discussed. The only thing that matters is that the force is perpendicular to the beam (and applied to the middle).

Comment: @Angelorf A top view??!! What kind of  ridiculous  "beam" problem is that? Moreover, John Alexiou was giving you the normal side view in his answer. l'm outta here.

Comment: What is so ridiculous about the force being horizontal? As if beams in practice only ever have vertical forces acting upon them. I think it's rather weird of you to assume that gravity must always play into the equation. Think for example of a bow.

Comment: Look. Even if the load F is applied horizontal, the weight of the beam unless insignificant compared to F ,will contribute to shear in the beam albeit horizontal shear. The real problem with your post is you provided no information on the assumptions you are making. Anyone looking at the question would think in term of a typical vertical load on a beam unless you indicated otherwise. In fact the answer you accepted obviously assumed vertical loading.  I have voted to close your post due to lack of details and clarity.